# Apache Ignite .Net Generate QueryEntity

Tags: ignite

```
private QueryEntity GenarateQueryEntity(Type type)
    {
        var attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(type);
        var isNeedToCache = false;
        foreach (var attr in attrs)
        {
            if (attr is CacheableAttribute)
            {
                isNeedToCache = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    if (isNeedToCache)
    {
        var queryEntity = new QueryEntity()
        {
            ValueType = type
        };

        var fields = new List<QueryField>();
        var indexes = new List<QueryIndex>();
        var props = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var propFieldAttrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(QuerySqlFieldAttribute), true);
            if (propFieldAttrs.Length > 0)
            {
                var item = propFieldAttrs.FirstOrDefault();
                var sqlAttr = item as QuerySqlFieldAttribute;
                if (sqlAttr.IsIndexed)
                {
                    indexes.Add(new QueryIndex(sqlAttr.IsDescending, QueryIndexType.Sorted, prop.Name)
                    {
                        InlineSize = sqlAttr.IndexInlineSize
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    if (CacheLibSettings.IndexColumn.IndexOf(prop.Name) > -1)
                    {
                        indexes.Add(new QueryIndex(sqlAttr.IsDescending, QueryIndexType.Sorted, prop.Name)
                        {
                            InlineSize = sqlAttr.IndexInlineSize
                        });
                    }
                }

                fields.Add(new QueryField()
                {
                    Name = prop.Name,
                    FieldType = prop.PropertyType,
                    IsKeyField = true,
                    NotNull = sqlAttr.NotNull,
                    DefaultValue = sqlAttr.DefaultValue,
                    Precision = sqlAttr.Precision,
                    Scale = sqlAttr.Scale
                });
            }

            if (CacheLibSettings.IndexColumn.IndexOf(prop.Name) > -1 && propFieldAttrs.Length == 0)
            {
                var sqlAttr = new QuerySqlFieldAttribute();

                indexes.Add(new QueryIndex(sqlAttr.IsDescending, QueryIndexType.Sorted, prop.Name)
                {
                    InlineSize = sqlAttr.IndexInlineSize
                });

                fields.Add(new QueryField()
                {
                    Name = prop.Name,
                    FieldType = prop.PropertyType,
                    IsKeyField = true,
                    NotNull = sqlAttr.NotNull,
                    DefaultValue = sqlAttr.DefaultValue,
                    Precision = sqlAttr.Precision,
                    Scale = sqlAttr.Scale
                });
            }
        }

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var propTextAttrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(QueryTextFieldAttribute), true);
            if (propTextAttrs.Length > 0)
            {
                fields.Add(new QueryField() { Name = prop.Name, FieldType = prop.PropertyType, IsKeyField = true });
                indexes.Add(new QueryIndex(false, QueryIndexType.FullText, prop.Name));
            }
        }
        if (fields.Any())
        {
            queryEntity.Fields = fields.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        }
        if (indexes.Any())
        {
            queryEntity.Indexes = indexes;
        }
        return queryEntity;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**this Genarate QueryEntity code.**

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

but

One is generated from Ignite New QueryEntity(Typeof (T)) and one is generated from GenarateQueryEntity(Typeof (T)).**I look at the Ignite source code where QueryIndexEx is a private class**.

**My question is: What can you do to generate the same result as Ignite New QueryEntity(Typeof (T)).**

Comment: Ignite source code:`indexes.Add(new QueryIndexEx(columnName, false, QueryIndexType.FullText, null));`

Comment: `QueryIndexEx` is an implementation detail, you should not have to worry about it. Does you code work?

Comment: My code doesn't work. Generating a QueryEntity and creating a cache are fine, but writing to a cache throws an exception and stops the server side.I use Ignite New QueryEnity() without any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

QueryIndexEx is only different in the regard that it has IndexGroups, which are null in your case.

Please share the specific error that you are getting: I'm pretty sure it is not caused by QueryIndex/QueryIndexEx difference.

Comment: Can you please share the solution for people's reference?

Comment: The reason for this error is that I have a field in my Type that is DateTime.I'll modify the IgniteConfiguration setting.
`var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
{BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration{Serializer = new BinaryReflectiveSerializer{ForceTimestamp = true}} };`
And I created QueryIndexEx, which inherits QueryIndex, just like the Ignite source, and now there is no problem.